# How to get document id or name in Android in Firestore db for passing on to another activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`.

I'm able to get each model and attributes of documents. But I want to get the document id.

I tried using `model.` Autosuggestions, but there was no document id or name

I have the following DealsHolder class. This is in Kotlin. However the rest of all the classes are in java.

```
package com.guidoapps.firestorerecycleradaptersample


import com.google.firebase.firestore.IgnoreExtraProperties

@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class DealsResponse(var title:String? = null,
                var price:String? = null,
                var dealPrice:String? = null,
                var image:String? = null,
                var description: String? = null)
```

The following function which I initialize in onCreate()

```
 private void getDealsList(){
        Query query = db.collection("deals").orderBy("dateTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<DealsResponse> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<DealsResponse>()
                .setQuery(query, DealsResponse.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<DealsResponse, MainActivity.DealsHolder>(response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.DealsHolder holder, int position, DealsResponse model) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.textTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
                holder.textPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
                holder.textDesc.setText(model.getDescription());
                holder.textDealPrice.setText(model.getDealPrice());

                holder.textPrice.setPaintFlags(holder.textPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(holder.imageView);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    Snackbar.make(DealsList, model.getTitle(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                });
            }
```

**Here in the holder.itemView onClickListener I want to get document ID in order to pass to another activity**

Then the following DealsHolder.

```
public class DealsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.title)
    TextView textTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.thumbnail)
    ImageView imageView;
    @BindView(R.id.description)
    TextView textDesc;
    @BindView(R.id.price)
    TextView textPrice;
    @BindView(R.id.dealPrice)
    TextView textDealPrice;

    public DealsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the adapter's `getSnapshots()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.DealsHolder holder, int position, DealsResponse model) {
    // ...
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        snapshot.getId();
        // ...
    }); 
}
```

The [getId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getId()) method returns the document's id, so in `collection/myDoc/someField`, `myDoc` would be the id.

If you know your data structure in the next activity, you can recreate the reference with that id through the standard `firestore.collection("foo").document("bar")` methods. If you're looking for the general solution, I use `getPath()` a bunch:

```
fun Bundle.putRef(ref: DocumentReference) = putString(REF_KEY, ref.path)

fun Bundle.getRef() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(getString(REF_KEY))
```

If you want the id in your model, use a custom `SnapshotParser`:

```
val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<DealsResponse>()
        .setQuery(query) {
            it.toObject(DealsResponse::class.java).apply { id = it.id }
        }
        .build()
```

Comment: What type does `snapshot.getId();` return?
Is there a way to know automatically in IDE what type it returns?

Comment: `String id = (String)snapshot.getId();` Is `id` okay for passing on to another activity as intent?

Comment: Is this the FireStore document Id in database and not the Recycle child's ID. I want database item ID so that I can get the item using Firestore DB calls. Like the PK in the db.

Comment: See my updated answer. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Can I pass `snapshot.getId()` to `putRef()`. Is it a `DocumentReference` type?

Comment: Nope, `getId()` is a Plain Jane `String`. You would pass the full ref of your snapshot to the `putRef` function. If you have a snapshot, the [`getReference()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getReference()) method will come in handy.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm currently doing this `String id = (String)snapshot.getId();` and passing it as intent. Where does the `getPath()` come from.  `snapshot.getPath()` doesn't seem to be valid.
`

Comment: The path comes from a reference: `val path: String = snapshot.reference.path`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID directly in `DealsHolder class`? Can you give an example

Comment: @SUPERCILEX  How to scroll to the particular id in recyclerview ?

Comment: You'd have to use `getSnapshots()` to find the index of the id, then call the recycler view scroll method.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(final GenericViewHolder holder, int position, FarmerModel model) {      
    DocumentReference ref = getItem(position).getReference();
    final String key = ref.getId();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.